# There was an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys', however the so called 'list' is a dictionary, what should I do?

Tags: python

Here's my Python code:

```
f=sys.stdin()
sys.stdin=open("crossroad.in","r")
sys.stdin=f
n=0
id={}
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x,y=input().split()
    int(x)
    int(y)
    id[x]=y
id=sorted(id)
count=0
keyList=sorted(id.keys())
for i,v in enumerate(keyList):
    if id[keyList[i + 1]] != id[keyList[i]] or id[keyList[i + 1]].value == id[keyList[i]].value:
        count+=1
k=open("crossroad.out","w")
k.write(count)
k.close()
```

However, Python gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\luogo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\Why_did_the_cow_cross_the_road", line 14, in <module>
    keyList=sorted(id.keys())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I did not understand that obviously id was a dictionary, but why did Python said it was a list? Pls answer my question. Thx!

Comment: `id=sorted(id)`, now `id` is a list of the sorted keys of the dict it used to be.

Comment: btw things like: `int(x)` do nothing at all except waste runtime.

Comment: and `id` is poor choice for a name - it's built-in function.